# "500: Internal Server Error" when trying to add a simple text file as an attachment via SharePoint 2013 REST API

Tags: javascript, 2013, sharepoint-addin

Using [SharePoint 2013 REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022.aspx#WorkLists), I am trying to attach a simple text file to a list's item.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: web.get_url() + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List1')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='readme.txt')",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "body": "Contents of file.",
        "content-length": 17,
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: doSuccesRestAPIAddAttachment,
    error: doErrorRestAPIAddAttachment
  });
```

I get the following error:

```
500:Internal Server Error
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code>-2147024883, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code><m:message xml:lang="en-US">The data is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000D)</m:message></m:error>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question! I read the page you linked to. The instructions there are a little bit confusing sometimes. After some experimenting I could add an attachment as you do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List1')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='readme.txt')",
    type: "POST",
    data: "Contents of file.",
    headers: {        
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    }
  });
```

I tested directly in the root web and didn't provide any callbacks just to keep it simple. I removed "Content-Length" Header because Chrome complained about "unsafe header". I put the "Content of file." into the request payload (`data: "Contents of file."`). The example below works for me. Say if it doesn't for you.

**Original answer:**

Maybe it is not the full answer but "body" shouldn't be inside headers. Try put it outside the body.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: web.get_url() + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List1')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='readme.txt')",
    type: "POST",
    body: "Contents of file.",
    headers: {        
        "content-length": 17,
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: doSuccesRestAPIAddAttachment,
    error: doErrorRestAPIAddAttachment
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, 
Unfortunately, the result is the same.

Comment: I experimented with your code and found a solution that works. See my updated answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I learned [a lot, too](http://chuvash.eu/2013/02/20/rest-api-add-a-plain-text-file-as-an-attachment-to-a-list-item/)

Comment: I tested this and it seems to only work for text files. How can I attach files like photos and pdfs?